# Any way to force a form to submit fields differently without using Javascript?

Tags: html

I have a form:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" value="hello" name="myname" />
</form>
```

If this form is submitted, I will end up at:

```
example.com/?myname=hello
```

What I would prefer is that when this gets submitted, I end up at:

```
example.com/hello
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No AFAIK, forms are not intend to be used like this so you will need Javascript to modify the default behavior, if you don't want to use Javascript then I suggest not trying to create dynamic web applications as pure HTML is static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change the way [form submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) works in HTML. (Using JavaScript, you can do transactions in a different way, without using HTML form submission.) When using `method="GET"`, the URL gets constructed in a specific way; when using `method="POST"`, the URL does not contain submitted data at all (it is sent outside the URL).

There is a trick that changes form submission in one way, but not quite the way you want. If the name of a control is `isindex`, then the control name and the equals sign are omitted; but the question mark is still there. That is, `<input type="text" value="hello" name="isindex" />` would result in `http://www.example.com/?hello`. And Chrome has broken this when they removed the remainders of support to the `isindex` element.

If, for some special reason, you really need to make a form create requests like `http://example.com/hello`, then the simplest way is to set up a very simple server-side script that accepts normal requests that result from HTML forms and just passes them forward after modifying the URL in a simple way.